# Merge Two Sorted Lists got a NoneType Error

Tags: python

Can someone help me understand why I am getting a 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'val' error? I added checks in the beginning for inputs that are None but I am still getting the same error. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!
[image]

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
class Solution(object):
    def mergeTwoLists(self, list1, list2):
        """
        :type list1: Optional[ListNode]
        :type list2: Optional[ListNode]
        :rtype: Optional[ListNode]
        """      
            
        p1 = list1
        p2 = list2
        newLL = ListNode(None,None)
        p3 = newLL
        
        if p1 is None and p2 is None:
            return newLL
        elif p1 is None:
            return p2
        elif p2 is None:
            return p1
        
        while p1 is not None or p2 is not None:
            if p1.val <= p2.val:
                p3.next = p1
                p1 = p1.next
            else:
                p3.next = p2
                p2 = p2.next
            p3 = p3.next
        
        if p1 is None:
            p3.next = p1
        else:
            p3.next = p2
            
        
        return newLL.next
```

Comment: `while p1 is not None or p2 is not None` so what if only one of them is `None`? (after an iteration of course, since you move on to `.next`, which might be `None` for either)

Comment: You want `and`, not `or`. Boolean logic...

Comment: Also note that your merge results in the original two lists also being modified - those variables will end up pointing to their respective first elements in the new resulting list and the original lists will no longer exists. I'm not sure that's the behaviour you had in mind.